# Using GCP identity providers in a Unity desktop/laptop client

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, identity, google-identity

Pretty certain that both Unity and Google/GCP intentionally don't support this, but here's the problem/challenge:

We have a Unity based/developed game with only PC/Mac/Linux (i.e. desktop/laptop) builds, with the client written in C#.  We would like to use the Google/GCP identity providers, but since our client is neither Android nor iOS (it's a desktop/laptop/linux/px/mac client) our only remaining option is to use the "Web" implementation.  But, the Unity game is not a website, it runs in the Unity-provided container on user's machine.  Since Google's/GCP's "Web" implementation is JavaScript based, and Unity does not seem to fully support JavaScript (or V8, etc) in a desktop/laptop build, we are wondering if anyone has managed to get Google's/GCP's "Phone" identity provider working with a Unity desktop/laptop/pc/linux/mac build

Comment: Google OAuth just uses simple HTTP endpoints. You can code that in just about any language. I wrote an article on how to do this in the CLI **curl**. The key part is the user must use a web browser to authenticate with Google. You can launch Chrome/Edge/etc on a desktop and capture the redirect.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for the comment - Tt seems like all Google/GCP/Firebase Identity Providers are *not* pure OAuth.  For example, for Facebook, you have to setup a Facebook "App Id" and have an "App Secret", and for "Phone" identity provider, that runs on SMS (on Google's end).  Also, the only OAuth(2) impls I've seen are all browser based.  I supposed I could F12 in chrome and trace the JavaScript/Ajax call, but seem like a big lift to do in C# without using a browser.  Can you point me to some example code that doesn't require a browser?

Comment: @JohnHanley [I couldn't edit my orig comment] just re-read your comment - yeah, that's what I figured, have to put a browser in the middle.  I've done that before but don't like having to pop open a browser and then try to ensure game/Unity client also takes back focus and is top most window - always seems to be issues (sometimes browser hangs, sometimes browser loses focus and get hidden behind other windows, sometimes browser throws up a million alerts, wants to upgrade, etc)